# Excel | Calculate the time difference

Tags: excel, time, difference, date-difference

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the difference in working hours. Depending on the amount, 30 minutes should be deducted for more than 6h (or equal to 6h) (corresponds to the break during working hours). If the working time is less than 6 hours, nothing will be deducted.

My formula in cell E2 looks like this.

```
=IF((D2-C2)>="6:00";D2-C2-"00:30";D2-C2)
```

(All cells have the time format.)

But this formula doesn't work. In the example above, I actually expect 9:30, but it outputs 10h.
Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because it sees `"6:00"` as text and does not convert it to a time.

add `--` before the `"6:00"`

```
=IF((D2-C2)>=--"6:00";D2-C2-"00:30";D2-C2)
```

[image]

Comment: I would never have figured it out, because with manual calculation D2-B2- "00:30" it also works without conversion.
Anyway, thanks, that was the quickest help I've ever received! :)